# how to automatically upload a file in another website from my own website such as uploading and sending file gmail from another web app automatically?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web-applications

Hi can someone tell me how to upload a file in this website http://hexserver.loria.fr from my web app ?

The thing is that you can see in the front page of the website there are two options for submitting molecules from my computer and then do docking...

So if I want to write such a script that will automatically upload the files in this website and then docking. the files will be in my mysql database.on submitting the files will be uploaded in this website.how to do it?

Any pointer towards solving this problem will be really helpful.

Comment: Please tag this question with the web technology your app is using. It is too vague at the moment.

Comment: I am using PHP and MySQL to build the app.

Comment: longest question title ever! :D

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple form you may use php or .net

Like;
http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/
and if you'are linux user you may add this to cron. Just learn form names.